# How to convert a string with characters in the int for the entire collection?

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, mongodb-compass

I have a collection of a similar look:

```
_id:5d0fe0dcfd8ea94eb4633222
Category:"Stripveiling (Nederlands)"
Category url:"https://www.catawiki.nl/a/11-stripveiling-nederlands"
Lot title:"Erwin Sels (Ersel) - Originele pagina"
Seller name:"Stripwereld"
Seller country:"Nederland"
Bids count:21
Winning bid:"€ 135"
Bid amount:"Closed"
Lot image:"https://assets.catawiki.nl/assets/2011/11/17/7/4/c/74c53540-f390-012e-..."
```

I need to change the "Winning bid" field to a int. That is, remove the currency sign and convert from string to int for the entire collection.

Nowhere in the documentation I could not find how to do it, do I really have to take every value with Python, remove the currency symbol and use the method update to do it? I have almost 8,000,000 records, it will be long.

How can I do this with the collection method? Or what is the quickest option to do this with Python?

Comment: are all the winning bids of the form "currency  number"?

Comment: @AbdeslemSMAHI yes

Comment: int(currency_string[1:].strip()) - this is assuming that there is a string in the first two characters are the currency symbol and the ' ' space character.

Comment: @MFK34 I have no problems with converting the string to a int with a python, especially since the strip() is not needed, you can just int(). I do not know how to carry out all the updates in mongodb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to convert the entire collection, you can do it with Aggregation pipeline.

You need to convert the currency to string using `$substr` and `$toInt(` or `$toDouble`, or `$convert` whatever suits your case) in the `$project` stage and `$out` as your last stage of aggregation. `$out` writes the result of the aggregtion pipeline to the given collection name.

But be careful while using `$out`. According to official mongodb documentation :

> **Create New Collection**
>
> The `$out` operation creates a new collection in the current database if one does not already exist. The
>   collection is not visible until the aggregation completes. If the
>   aggregation fails, MongoDB does not create the collection.
>
> **Replace Existing Collection**
>
> If the collection specified by the `$out` operation already exists, then upon completion of the
>   aggregation, the `$out` stage atomically replaces the existing
>   collection with the new results collection. Specifically, the `$out`
>   operation:
>
> 1. Creates a temp collection.
> 2. Copies the indexes from the existing
>      collection to the temp collection.
> 3. Inserts the documents into the
>      temp collection.
> 4. Calls db.collection.renameCollection with
>      dropTarget: true to rename the temp collection to the destination
>      collection.
>
> The `$out` operation does not change any indexes that existed on the
>   previous collection. If the aggregation fails, the `$out` operation
>   makes no changes to the pre-existing collection.

Try this :

```
db.collection_name.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            category : "$category",
            category_name : "$category_name",
            lot_title : "$lot_title",
            seller_name : "$seller_name",
            seller_country : "$seller_country",
            bid_count : "$bid_count",
            winning_bid : { $toInt : {$substr : ["$winning_bid",2,-1]}},
            bid_amount : "$bid_amount",
            lot_image : "$lot_image"
        }
    },{
        $out : "collection_name"
    }
])
```

you might need to use `allowDiskUse : true` as an option to aggregation pipeline, as you have a lots of documents, and it may surpass 16MB mongodb limit.

**Don't forget to replace `collection_name` with actual collection name , and include all the required field in the `$project` stage which you need in the collection. And please double check the value first  either with a different `temporary_collection` or just by removing the $out stage and checking the result of `aggregation` pipeline.**

For detailed information read official mongodb documentation [$out](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/), [$toInt](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toInt/), [$toDouble](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toDouble/), [$convert,](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/convert/) [$substr](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/substr/) and [allowDiskUse](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/aggregate/).

Comment: Hello. It does not work for me, because my version of mongodb is 3.6.4. This feature appeared in version 4.0.

Comment: I think it was available from MongoDB version 2.6, later changed in version 3.2(with additional features), so it should work for you. You can confirm from official $out documentation as well : https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/

Comment: i mean $toInt and $convert is new in version 4.0. u can check it.

Comment: for now im backing up my db and after restore into new verion, after that im try u code.

Comment: oh okay, you were talking about `$toInt` and `$convert`. I see

Comment: Oh, I completely forgot. I have some cells where instead of a number there is "No bids" and now I have the following error:Failed to parse number ' bids' in $convert with no onError value: Bad digit " " while parsing bids

Comment: can i get around this somehow?

Comment: maybe I should replace the line "No bids" with "€ 0" and after that use ur code?

Comment: yes do that, replace code is pretty easy, `.update({winning_bid : "No bins"},{$set : {winning_bid : "€ 0"}},{multi:true})`. Dont forget `multi:true`, to update all the docs, otherwise it will only update the first matched doc.

Comment: can i somehow use this command in aggregation? I easily redid your past commands: I simply inserted the “body” of the function into the aggregation $project and aggregation $out, but with the update I can not find the desired aggregation

Comment: why dont you just run this update command before performing the aggregation query?

Comment: I completely screwed up with the database. I called her "catawiki lots" with a space and now i cant connect to it anyway

Comment: only what i can its use Compass and aggregations

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195921/discussion-between-ravi-shankar-bharti-and-kshnkvn).

Comment: oh wait i found solution: db["catawiki lots"].renameCollection("catawiki_lots");