# Multiple search with replacement in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

Database with the following structure:

```
_id:5d0fe110d7b8c01a4c633222
Category:"Stripveiling (Nederlands)"
Lot title:"Blake en Mortimer - S.O.S. Meteoren - 1e Druk HC 1959"
Seller name:"Stripsmagazijn"
Seller country:"Nederland"
Bids count:22
Winning bid:"€ 1.950"
Bid amount:"Closed"
```

I need to change the value of the "Winning bid" from "1.950" to "1950".
There may be many meanings and they may be different, therefore
$replaceOne() does not suit.
Can someone help with this?

Comment: what do you mean by "many meanings, and they may be different". Can you provide some examples?

Comment: @RaviShankarBharti these can be different numbers, for example: 225.568, 7.456, 13.565, 1.560

Comment: is there a decimal at the thousand's place always? and are all of them string?

Comment: if there are less docs like that, you can manually change them

Comment: @RaviShankarBharti yes, always and it all a string. And a lot of them. Idk, I may have found a solution: winning_bid: {$trim: {input: "$Winning bid", chars: "."}} but when i run i have error: insert for $out failed: { ok: 0.0, errmsg: "operation exceeded time limit", code: 50, codeName: "MaxTimeMSExpired" }

Comment: $trim wont work as it only removes characters from beginning and end of array only

Comment: @RaviShankarBharti any other suggestions?

Comment: should i give the answer continuing with the previous aggregate query? i have a possible answer using aggregation pipeline and $out.

Comment: @RaviShankarBharti ok i'm listening to you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Continuing with Answer from your [last post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56813094/how-to-convert-a-string-with-characters-in-the-int-for-the-entire-collectionhttps://).**

I think you can use [$split](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/split/https://) and [$reduce](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/) in your `$project` stage with `$out` stage as the last stage of the pipeline to convert all such occurances in your db.

The idea is to `split` the string with `"."` and `concat` the array back to form a string but without `"."`, and after that you can continue with the normal process.

You are getting the error `$out failed: { ok: 0.0, errmsg: "operation exceeded time limit", code: 50, codeName: "MaxTimeMSExpired" }` because of the timeout, you can increase the default timeout using [$maxTimeMS](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/meta/maxTimeMS/)

```
db.collection_name.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            category : "$category",
            category_name : "$category_name",
            lot_title : "$lot_title",
            seller_name : "$seller_name",
            seller_country : "$seller_country",
            bid_count : "$bid_count",
            winning_bid : { 
                $toInt : {
                    $substr : [
                        {
                            $reduce : {
                                input : { $split : ["$winning_bid","."]}},
                                initialValue: "",
                                in: { $concat : ["$$value", "$$this"] }
                            }
                        },
                        2,
                        -1
                    ]
                }
            },
            bid_amount : "$bid_amount",
            lot_image : "$lot_image"
        }
    },{
        $out : "collection_name"
    }
]).maxTimeMS(100)
```

you can increase the timeout as per your needs.

I havent tested the code, it should work theoritically, but you get the idea, you can change the code to suit your need.

Comment: error: can't convert from BSON type array to String

Comment: oh yea, $concatArray concats arrays, i will update the answer

Comment: i found a solution: winning_bid: {$toInt: {$arrayElemAt: [{$split: [{$trim: {input: "$Winning bid", chars: "€ "}}, "."]}, 0]}}

Comment: but i have some strange error: insert for $out failed: { ok: 0.0, errmsg: "operation exceeded time limit", code: 50, codeName: "MaxTimeMSExpired" }

Comment: yea, that is because of timeout error, use $maxTimeMS to increase the timeout.

Comment: where i mus use it?

Comment: in out window i have only: 'catawiki_lots_new' no other constructions and symbols

Comment: Have a look a the documentation https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/meta/maxTimeMS/

Comment: i have updated the code, you can have a look. And `out : catawiki_lots_new` looks good

Comment: .maxTimeMS(100) does not work: db.catawiki_lots.aggregate(...).maxTimeMS is not a function

Comment: also i tied to add maxTimeMS=100 in aggregate argument: db.catawiki_lots.aggregate([], maxTimeMS=100) : Error: assert failed : 'aggregateOptions' argument must be an object

Comment: the error is true, you need to prove an object, try this : `db.catawiki_lots.aggregate([], {maxTimeMS:100}) `